# dry-validation; Dry::Validation.Schema for undefined method `Schema' for Dry::Validation:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I tried using `dry-validation`(https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-validation).

However I got the error with `Dry::Validation.Schema` and can't do anything.

The error says;

```
Dry::Validation.Schema for undefined method `Schema' for Dry::Validation:Module
```

`dry-validation` gem is included correctly.

Any ideas?

```
[21] pry(main)> Dry::Validation.public_methods
=> [:Result,
 :Predicate,
 :pretty_print_cycle,
 :module_exec,
 :class_exec,
 :module_eval,
 :class_eval,
 :included_modules,
 :include?,
 :name,
 :ancestors,
 :instance_methods,
 :public_instance_methods,
 :protected_instance_methods,
 :private_instance_methods,
 :constants,
 :const_get,
 :const_set,
 :const_defined?,
 :class_variables,
 :remove_class_variable,
 :class_variable_get,
 :class_variable_set,
 :class_variable_defined?,
 :public_constant,
 :private_constant,
 :deprecate_constant,
 :singleton_class?,
 :method_defined?,
 :mattr_reader,
 :protected_method_defined?,
 :private_class_method,
 :mattr_writer,
 :public_method_defined?,
 :private_method_defined?,
 :mattr_accessor,
 :public_class_method,
 :cattr_reader,
 :cattr_writer,
 :cattr_accessor,
 :<,
 :>,
 :namespace_name,
 :parent_name,
 :local_constants,
 :deprecate,
 :qualified_const_defined?,
 :qualified_const_get,
 :psych_yaml_as,
 :yaml_as,
 :qualified_const_set,
 :parent,
 :remove_possible_method,
 :pretty_print,
 :<=>,
 :<=,
 :>=,
 :==,
 :===,
 :delegate,
 :prepend,
 :redefine_method,
 :freeze,
 :inspect,
 :attr_internal_reader,
 :attr_internal_writer,
 :attr_internal_accessor,
 :attr_internal,
 :methods_transplantable?,
 :to_s,
 :autoload,
 :autoload?,
 :parents,
 :alias_method_chain,
 :anonymous?,
 :alias_attribute,
 :instance_method,
 :public_instance_method,
 :reachable?,
 :class_name,
 :include,
 :delay,
 :delay_for,
 :delay_until,
 :sidekiq_delay,
 :sidekiq_delay_for,
 :sidekiq_delay_until,
 :const_missing,
 :guess_for_anonymous,
 :unloadable,
 :concerning,
 :concern,
 :`,
 :to_yaml,
 :to_yaml_properties,
 :blank?,
 :present?,
 :to_json,
 :psych_to_yaml,
 :presence,
 :deep_dup,
 :acts_like?,
 :duplicable?,
 :try,
 :try!,
 :in?,
 :presence_in,
 :to_param,
 :to_query,
 :as_json,
 :instance_values,
 :instance_variable_names,
 :to_json_with_active_support_encoder,
 :to_json_without_active_support_encoder,
 :with_options,
 :html_safe?,
 :deep_clone,
 :dclone,
 :pry,
 :__binding__,
 :pretty_print_instance_variables,
 :pretty_print_inspect,
 :require_dependency,
 :require_or_load,
 :load_dependency,
 :to_ruby,
 :to_v8,
 :instance_of?,
 :public_send,
 :instance_variable_get,
 :instance_variable_set,
 :instance_variable_defined?,
 :remove_instance_variable,
 :private_methods,
 :kind_of?,
 :instance_variables,
 :tap,
 :define_singleton_method,
 :suppress_warnings,
 :is_a?,
 :extend,
 :silence_warnings,
 :byebug,
 :debugger,
 :to_enum,
 :enum_for,
 :with_warnings,
 :enable_warnings,
 :silence_stderr,
 :silence_stream,
 :suppress,
 :capture,
 :quietly,
 :silence,
 :=~,
 :!~,
 :eql?,
 :respond_to?,
 :display,
 :pretty_inspect,
 :object_id,
 :send,
 :gem,
 :method,
 :public_method,
 :singleton_method,
 :nil?,
 :hash,
 :class,
 :singleton_class,
 :clone,
 :dup,
 :itself,
 :taint,
 :tainted?,
 :untaint,
 :untrust,
 :trust,
 :untrusted?,
 :methods,
 :protected_methods,
 :frozen?,
 :public_methods,
 :singleton_methods,
 :!,
 :!=,
 :__send__,
 :equal?,
 :instance_eval,
 :instance_exec,
 :__id__]
```

Answer (score 1):

I explicitly specify the gem

```
 'dry-validation', git: 'git://github.com/dry-rb/dry-validation.git', tag: 'v0.10.3'
```

and then works.